# onactivityResult get called at the wrong time

Tags: android, fragment, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I'm using this code

```
      final Intent i = new Intent();
      i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
      i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
      i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
      i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
      i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
      parentFragment.startActivityForResult(i, Constants.PERMISSIONS);
```

to let the user the option to change settings in run time. this code occurs when the user is clicking on a button. 
what I'm trying to do is to get the information of his choice, for this I'm using **onActivityResult** method. But I noticed that this method is getting called when the user is clicked on the button and entered to the settings screen.

**This code is found in Fragment and not in Activity.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem. As I mentioned in my question - onActivityResult was called immediately after startActivityForResult.

The cause for this problem was    **i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);**